# Php dom document dynamic select option

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to convert div data to select element using php domdocument,I save them in mysql and serialize them to the screen as an element.
I separated the data with / but how do I call them in select option , my code is as below
error = syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'

Php code:

```
 $examplcd= array();
 $myhtml = $_POST['divData'];
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->loadHTML($myhtml);
 $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
 foreach ($tags as $tag) {
  array_push($examplcd, htmlentities('<select id="myid">'.
   $mtrl = explode('/', $tag->nodeValue);
   $mtrl[0]; 
    foreach ($mtrl as $mtrlshoot) {
     .'<option>'.$mtrlshoot.'</option>'.
    }
 .'</select>'));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, foreach worked when I got it out,it might work for you

```
$mtrl = explode('/', $tag->nodeValue);
$mtrl[0]; 
$myptn = "";
foreach ($mtrl as $mtrlshoot) { 
 $myptn.="<option value=".$mtrlshoot.">".$mtrlshoot."</option>";
};
```

And appen code :

```
array_push($examplcd, htmlentities('<select id="myid">'.$myptn.'</select>'));
```